# Caching Behavior With FileStream

Tags: c#, file, caching

I believe I am seeing "caching behavior" using

`try catch finally`

with a  FileStream object.

I am trying to save a `PictureBox` image to a network file path that looks like this:

`\\img_srv\permitimages\2014\Building\4454-1.tif`

Here is the code performing the save and incrementing file names:

```
public void save_file_name()
{
    gen_full_yr_image_path();
    string image_path = get_full_yr_image_path();
    bool does_file_exist = true;
    FileStream test_file = null;

    while (does_file_exist)
    {
        try
        {
            test_file = new FileStream(image_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            test_file.Close();
            test_file.Dispose();
            test_file = null;

            gen_image_file_name();
            gen_full_yr_image_path();
            image_path = get_full_yr_image_path();
        }

        catch
        {
            does_file_exist = false;
            test_file = new FileStream(image_path, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
            test_file.Close();
            test_file.Dispose();
            test_file = null;
            m_scanned_pic.Image.Save(image_path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
        }

        finally
        {
            if (null != test_file)
            {
               test_file.Close();
               test_file.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior I'm seeing is as follows:

If `\\img_srv\permitimages\2014\Building\4454-1.tif` ***does not exist***, an exception results from trying to open the file. That is the expected behavior.

However, if `\\img_srv\permitimages\2014\Building\4454-1.tif` ***does exist***, the next incremental file name

`\\img_srv\permitimages\2014\Building\4454-2.tif`

created after

`test_file = new FileStream(image_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);`

and which I have verified does not already exist, does not create a file not found exception. I believe some kind of caching behavior is going on, and am wondering what to do to "reset" everything.

I know this isn't supposed to happen, but I really have verified this. That is why I believe the prior file's existing is somehow being cached in my code. I'm just not seeing where.

Comment: Not going to touch the "caching behavior" part, but you do know there's method called File.Exists(), right? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt I tried using File.Exists(path), and that also exhibited the same caching behavior.

Comment: I'm not aware of any caching behavior in such cases. You might want to post additional code to show exactly what's going on (gen_full_yr_image_path(), and get_full_yr_image_path() in particular), but I would definitely encourage you to keep the File.Exists() check in favor of the current implementation.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Actually, posts in SO recommended `try catch` over `File.Exists()` to avoid creating a file while one was being created by another process. That's why I chose try catch finally. I have looked at the result of calling the other code -- not currently posted -- and it creates the same path, but with an incremented file name. I think the network path is being cached, but do not know how to clear it.

Comment: Also: The catch part looks dodgy: You're creating a FileStream, presumably in order to create the file, then closing & disposing it, and then Saving the image to it. I have no idea what kind of type "Image" is, but doesn't it know itself how to create files if they don't exist?

Comment: So we're in a multithreaded scenario here? All the more reason to post additional code.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt It is redundant. The PictureBox.Image.Save just saves and works if permissions are correct. The share being saved to has the correct settings to allow writes. My only alternative is to get a directory listing and search through it. No, it's not a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: And you've confirmed the file name variable `image_file` is actually being changed properly for the next loop?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Yes, and I believe the problem is not closing the file stream in the catch, which has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was corrected after `test_file.Close();` was added to `catch`, which is already updated in the original post. I've seen similar behavior to this with database cursors that are not closed.

Comment: You probably should make yourself familiar with `using`. Right now your disposal code is the superstitious dispose pattern. Closing 3 times does no good.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make a note and look at this next week.